Divergence in probability using sub-sequences that converge almost surely
This is a question from Chapter 3 Section 4 of Cinlar's Probability and Stochastic (Ex. 3.15). The question is:

The sequence $(X_n)$ is said to diverge to $+\infty$ in probability if $P(X_n>b)\rightarrow 1$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for every $b$ in $\mathbb{R}_+$. If $(X_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$ and $(Y_n)$ converges to $Y$, both in probability, then $(X_n+Y_n)$ diverges to $+\infty$ in probability. Show.

My first attempt to proving it was by manipulating $X_n+Y_n$ and expressing it in terms of $X_n, Y_n$ and $Y$. This approach worked, but I was thinking about following the method used to prove that $X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{P} Y \implies X_n+Y_n \xrightarrow{P} X+Y$. First I showed that $\exists N\subset \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $X_n\xrightarrow{a.s.} \infty$ along $N$. Then $Y_n \xrightarrow{P} Y \implies Y_n \xrightarrow{P} Y$ along $N$ as well. So $\exists N'\subset N$ s.t. $Y_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} Y$. Hence, for every sub-sequence of $(X_n+Y_n), \exists$ further sub-sequence that converges a.s. to $\infty \implies X_n+Y_n \xrightarrow{P} \infty$. The full proof is in the picture.

I'd like to know if my attempt is correct or if I need to make any changes. Thanks in advance.
